# Retirar parte de uma string - SQL Server

Tags: sql

Eu tenho gravado em uma coluna do banco de dados o nome de um arquivo com extensão (ARQUIVO.txt).
Eu preciso mostrar em um SELECT somente o ARQUIVO ao invés de ARQUIVO.txt

Alguém sabe como fazer?

Comment: qual banco de dados? pesquise pela função REPLACE dele.
SELECT REPLACE('', '', '') FROM table..

Comment: SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se você souber exatamente qual a extensão, você pode usar REPLACE

```
SELECT REPLACE(file, '.txt', '') FROM table;
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186862.aspx

ou, se forem várias extensões, então um SUBSTRING é melhor:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(file, -4, 4) FROM table;
```

Comment: Funcionou! Obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Fiz um exemplo que atende a vários casos.
Exemplo: arquivo.txt, arquivo.secreto.txt, arquivo.jpeg.

```
Declare @campo varchar(100) = 'Arquivo.txt'
select left(@campo,len(@campo) - charindex('.',reverse(@campo)) ) resultado
```